# How to hardcode chart data in my Model then have my Controller pull it from there to display it. Using Highcharts

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

Im using highcharts, right now I have an example chart.  Before I pull data from the api, I want to hardcode my own data into the chart.  Right now I have my chart data in my javascript file.  I want to hardcode the data in my Model, and then have my Controller pull it from there, to display it on the chart in my View.  My current code is below.  Thanks in advance.

Javascript file below:

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                borderColor: 'gray',
                borderWidth: 2,
                // borderRadius: 20,
                backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
                stops: [
                    [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                    [1, 'rgb(200, 200, 255)']
                ]
            },
                zoomType: 'x',
                spacingRight: 20
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Bitcoin Price'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                    'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' :
                    'Drag your finger over the plot to zoom in'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                maxZoom: 14 * 24 * 3600000, // fourteen days
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Price'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared: true
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
                        stops: [
                            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                            [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                        ]
                    },
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    shadow: false,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    threshold: null
                }
            },

            series: [{
                type: 'area',
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                pointStart: Date.UTC(2006, 0, 01),
                data: [
                    0.8446, 0.8445, 0.8444, 0.8451,    0.8418, 0.8264,    0.8258, 0.8232,    0.8233, 0.8258, and so on....these are just random numbers to fill in the data.....

                ]
            }]
        });

    $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/chart/ajax_get_chart", // the URL of the controller action method
               data: null, // optional data
               success: function(result) {
                    // do something with result
               },                
               error : function(req, status, error) {
                    // do something with error   
               }
           });

    });
```

In my Controller I have:

```
public function ajax_get_chart() {

}
```

In my Model I have:

```
public function ajax_get_chart() {

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it in this way.

have a method something like

```
generateChart(data){
//all the chart related stuff
}
```

in ajax call success call back make a call to the generateChart method with the data you have got

```
$.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/chart/ajax_get_chart", // the URL of the controller action method
               data: null, // optional data
               success: function(response) {
                  generateChart(response)
               },                
               error : function(req, status, error) {
                    // do something with error   
               }
           });
```

so fially the data in the model, ajax call in the controller and the gerateChart will give you the view.

hope this will help.